# Creating custom history back and forwards buttons using a React hook

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-router-dom, browser-history, html5-history

I would like to create custom history back and forwards buttons using a React hook.

For reference, in case it helps, I'm trying to replicate the behaviour that can be seen in Spotify's web app. Their custom forwards and back buttons integrate seamlessly with the browser history buttons.

I think I have it mostly working, but with one issue. Here is my React hook:

```js
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { useHistory } from 'react-router-dom';

const useNavigationHistory = () => {
  const history = useHistory();

  const [length, setLength] = useState(0);
  const [direction, setDirection] = useState(null);
  const [historyStack, setHistoryStack] = useState([]);
  const [futureStack, setFutureStack] = useState([]);

  const canGoBack = historyStack.length > 0;
  const canGoForward = futureStack.length > 0;

  const goBack = () => {
    if (canGoBack) {
      history.goBack();
    }
  };

  const goForward = () => {
    if (canGoForward) {
      history.goForward();
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    return history.listen((location, action) => {
      // if action is PUSH we are going forwards
      if (action === 'PUSH') {
        setDirection('forwards');
        setLength(length + 1);
        // add the new location to the historyStack
        setHistoryStack([...historyStack, location.pathname]);
        // clear the futureStack because it is not possible to go forward from here
        setFutureStack([]);
      }
      // if action is POP we could be going forwards or backwards
      else if (action === 'POP') {
        // determine if we are going forwards or backwards
        if (futureStack.length > 0 && futureStack[futureStack.length - 1] === location.pathname) {
          setDirection('forwards');
          // if we are going forwards, pop the futureStack and push it onto the historyStack
          setHistoryStack([...historyStack, futureStack.pop()]);
          setFutureStack(futureStack);
        } else {
          setDirection('backwards');
          // if we are going backwards, pop the historyStack and push it onto the futureStack
          setFutureStack([...futureStack, historyStack.pop()]);
          setHistoryStack(historyStack);
        }
        setLength(historyStack.length);
      }
    });
  }, [history, length, historyStack, futureStack]);

  return { canGoBack, canGoForward, goBack, goForward };
};

export default useNavigationHistory;
```

In my testing this all seems to work fine when navigating forwards and back between various different pages.

### The Problem

If I navigate forwards by alternating between the same 2 pages, for example:

```
/home
/about
/home
/about
/home
/about
```

...then my logic to determine if we are going forwards or backwards falls apart.

I think it's this line:

```
if (futureStack.length > 0 && futureStack[futureStack.length - 1] === location.pathname) {
```

because the forwards pathname and the backwards pathname are identical, so it thinks I'm going forwards even when I'm going backwards.

I've been trying to figure out how I could resolve this, but haven't managed to get something working.

Is anyone able to help?

Maybe my solution is flawed and I need an entirely different method, I'm not sure.

Comment: You seem to be changing the default forward/backward navigation logic from that of the browser. React-Router already "seamlessly integrates" with the browser, is there any issue with just using `history.goBack()` and `history.goForward()` and trusting the browser to handle it? You kind of seem to be "re-inventing the wheel" here.

Comment: @DrewReese I want my app to be usable without browser controls visible, e.g. as a PWA or packaged and distributed for desktop, hence adding some custom controls.
And I don't want to use the default `history.goBack()` etc because that could take you to another URL that isn't my app, so I want my controls to be scoped to my site only.
I see lots of web apps do this exact same thing, I just want to get it working.

Comment: Just because you see other websites doing something doesn't mean it's normal or acceptable. If users would like to navigate back to wherever they were before navigating into your app/page, they should be allowed to. Please ***don't*** trap users in your app/on your page, it's poor UI/UX.

Comment: @DrewReese Thanks, I understand where you're coming from. I would like to avoid opinionated discussion and just get a technical solution to what I'm trying to achieve, thank you.